# How to grant "resourcemanager.projects.create" permission?

Tags: console, smtp, resourcemanager, google-cloud-resource-manager

I want to use G-Suite SMTP server on WP Mail SMTP plugin on my WP website. But when I'm trying to create a project from my Google Cloud console. I get this error:

> You do not have the required "resourcemanager.projects.create" permission to create projects in this location.

What can I try to resolve it?